# Check PostgreSQL tables before insertion

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I have to insert several values in a PgSQL Table using these variables

```
$knr = $reader->getAttribute('Nr');
$kname = $reader->getAttribute('Name');
```

And this insertion code:

```
$SQL = "";
$SQL .= "SELECT
(konzern).knr AS knr, (konzern).name AS name
FROM konzern";
$SQL .= "INSERT INTO konzern (";
$SQL .= "knr, name";
$SQL .= ") VALUES (";
$SQL .= "'".$knr."', '".$kname."'";
$SQL .= ");".PHP_EOL;
```

And I want to check if the table "Konzern" already have a row with the $knr and if yes it should insert into this, if not it should create a new row

```
$query = doQuery("select nr from konzern where knr = '".$knr."'");
$num_rows = ($query->num_rows);
if ($num_rows > 0) {
    // do nothing
}
else {
    $sql .= "select nextval('konzern_nr_seq')";
}
```

But I have some problems puting this into the right order.
Can someone complete this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single query in this way :

```
INSERT INTO konzern SELECT val1, val2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT nr from konzern where knr = 'var1'
)
```

Implement this approach it will be more straigth forward .

*And remember to use query parameters instead of concatenating the query text, to avoid SQL Injections.*